Salesforce: Lookup Field in Screen Flow is not showing records when searching for a record
For the New Quote button created from Aura its showing the results for Primary Contact. Lookup field when a record is searched,

but it is not showing records for Primary Contact. in New Quote. Button which is a screen flow,

There is Lookup on Contact called Primary Contact. when i search for a record it doesn't show any records shows the results when i click on show all results
This is the Lookup Filter
(((Primary Contact.: Account Name ID EQUALS Quote: Account ID) OR
 (Primary Contact.: Account Name ID EQUALS Quote: End User ID)) AND
 ((Primary Contact.: Status EQUALS Active) OR 
 ((Primary Contact.: Status EQUALS Inactive) AND 
 (Primary Contact.: Status Reason Code EQUALS Contact Life Cycle))) AND
 (Current User: Division (Level 1) EQUALS AMS)) OR 
 (Current User Profile: Name EQUALS System Administrator) OR 
 (Current User Profile: Name EQUALS Data Migration) OR 
 (Current User: Division (Level 1) NOT EQUAL TO AMS)

How to fix this issue? Can anyone suggest a solution?

that's a really complicated filter - I suggest you stash it somewhere and start with a minimal filter that works, then add one clause at a time until it breaks
